# Why last 3 columns fall into one or two when saving database as CSV file?

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, export-to-csv

**Why last 3 columns fall into one or two when saving database as CSV file ?**

Almost all the columns were saved right, except for the 3 last ones

[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE5Cr.png)

**Here is the code:**

```
//export DB to CSV file
    public static String currentFilePathOfsavingCSVtoSD;
    public static void exportDBtoCSVsaveonSD() {

        String currentDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        File dbFile = new File("/data/data/" + "com.exactly.scooltr.inventoryAppBasic" + "/databases/" + DATABASE_NAME);
        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/" + main_folder+ "/CSV_files/");
        if (!exportDir.exists()) {
            exportDir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(exportDir, "("+currentDateString+")"+"simpleinventorycsv.csv");
        currentFilePathOfsavingCSVtoSD = file.toString();
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME+", "+ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE+", "+
                            ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY+", "+ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_SOLD+", "+
                            ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_BARCODE+", "+ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_LOCATION+", "+
                            ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_CATEGORY+", "+ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NOTE +
                             " FROM " + ProductContract.ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME , null);
            csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
            while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
                //Columns I want to export
                String arrStr[] = {curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),curCSV.getString(3),curCSV.getString(4),curCSV.getString(5)+curCSV.getString(6)+curCSV.getString(7)};
                csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
            }
            successSavingAsCSV=true;
            csvWrite.close();
            curCSV.close();
        } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
            Log.e("ProductProvider", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Please show the csv file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is passing the last three columns as you are concatenating them by using **`+`** instead of using **`,`** to treat them as separate arguments

i.e. :-

```
String arrStr[] = {
    curCSV.getString(0),
    curCSV.getString(1), 
    curCSV.getString(2),
    curCSV.getString(3),
    curCSV.getString(4),
    curCSV.getString(5)+curCSV.getString(6)+curCSV.getString(7)
};
```

Should be :-

```
String arrStr[] = {
    curCSV.getString(0),
    curCSV.getString(1), 
    curCSV.getString(2),
    curCSV.getString(3),
    curCSV.getString(4),
    curCSV.getString(5), //<<<< comma instead of +
    curCSV.getString(6), //<<<< comma instead of +
    curCSV.getString(7)
};
```

However the following would be far more resilient as it uses calculated offsets as opposed to hard coded column index offsets :-

```
String arrStr[] = {
    curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME)),
    curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE)), 
    curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY)),
    curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_SOLD)),
    curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_BARCODE)),
    curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_LOCATION)), //<<<< comma instead of +
    curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_CATEGORY)), //<<<< comma instead of +
    curCSV.getString(curCSV.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NOTE))
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your full answer, @MikeT. It's working now !))

Comment: Would appreciate you ticking as an answer.